# Android make custom edittext with shape

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-shape

how can i make this custom edittext using shape please ?

http://www.noelshack.com/2015-15-1428418773-form3.png

I've tried `android:drawableLeft` but the result's not matching

**rectangle_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#3498db" />
</shape>
```

**shape.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rectangle_shape"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/user"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your current code so we can know in more detail what you tried and where you got it wrong. ;)

Comment: post your code and explain what is your exact requirement please